# postgresql finding the unique tuples

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables

```
create table JobStaff (
    Job      integer references Job(id),
    staff       integer references Staff(id),
    role        integer references JobRole(id),
    primary key (course,staff,role)
);

create table Job (
    cid         integer, 
    branch     integer not null references Branches(id),
    term        integer not null references Terms(id),
    primary key (id)
);
```

and im trying to find all the jobs that don't have staffs attached to them. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The column `course` you use in the primary key is missing in the definition? And `id` is missing in table `job` ..

Comment: It makes life easier for those trying to answer you if the tables you show in your code sample can actually be created by copy/paste.  A little sample data doesn't hurt either.  In the future, please try that out in an empty test database before posting.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yeah that was my bad i copied and pasted that from an old table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, fix your create table queries like so:

```
create table JobStaff (
    jobid         integer references Job(id),
    staffid       integer references Staff(id),
    roleid        integer references JobRole(id),
    primary key (jobid,staffid,roleid)
);

create table Job (
    id          integer, 
    branch      integer not null references Branches(id),
    term        integer not null references Terms(id),
    primary key (id)
);
```

- `JobStaff`'s primary key should use `jobid` instead of `courseid`;
- `Job`'s first column should be `id` instead of `cid`;
- I recommend using significative column names like `jobid` when using references to id column.

Then for your query, you'll need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Job
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT jobid FROM JobStaff);
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
SELECT *
FROM   job j
LEFT   JOIN jobstaff js ON js.job = j.id
WHERE  js.job IS NULL;
```

I wrote a more comprehensive answer for this kind of problem just yesterday on dba.SE:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16651/3684

Answer (score 1):

Using the definitions from Francis P's answer, but with `REFERENCES` omitted to tables not defined, I suggest this (a variant of one of the options from Erwin Brandstetter's comprehensive answer that he linked to in his answer) for PostgreSQL version 8.4 or later:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Job j
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM jobstaff js WHERE js.jobid = j.id);
```

In recent versions of PostgreSQL this will optimize the same as Erwin answer, except that it will only show columns from Job, which seems to be what you want.  The narrower row (omitting the unneeded columns) will probably perform slightly better at scale.  In older versions of PostgreSQL (before version 8.4) you are likely to get better performance with the option shown in Erwin's answer; semi-join and anti-join optimizations were added in 8.4, and the `LEFT JOIN` trick was the best way to emulate it.

Note that `DISTINCT` is not needed in this case.

I recommend against `NOT IN` for cases like this in PostgreSQL.  While it doesn't logically matter here because the `PRIMARY KEY` constraints will implicitly force the columns involved to `NOT NULL`, `NOT IN` has surprising semantics when NULL capable columns are involved, and the logic to handle those semantics is not as efficient as `NOT EXISTS` or the `LEFT JOIN`.  PostgreSQL doesn't burn processing time to see if the arguments are provably `NOT NULL`, so you get the poor optimization regardless.